# Model for predicting delivery packages for an address

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, model, lags

I want to predict how many number of days in the following week, an address will receive packages. So there are 8 labels, from 0 to 7. 0 means the address has no package. 7 means it gets packages everyday of the week. I don't have much information about the package and address. I only know the zip code for an address, the size and weight for an package.

Now I am building a multi-layer classification model with lag variable. I used past 10-week data for each address. Each week's data is a feature.

I also tried the address's geography, population density information as my label, but they don't have any help on the prediction.

I'm stuck on finding more useful features. Any suggestion on potential features and the model type itself?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of features I could think of are distance between the distribution center(s) and the delivery address, demographics (gender, age, income, etc.), weather